# Is there a list of wireless adapters that work on Ubuntu with no hassle?

Tags: wireless, networking, adapter

I've got Ubuntu 10.04 installed, and I've just spent 2 hours trying to get my linksys WUSB54GC wireless USB adapter to work with no luck. I've tried the ndiswrapper, pulling the .inf files off my installation cd and a dozen other suggestions from the ubuntu forums.

I want a wireless adapter (usb or pci) that just works without all this hassle. Is there a compatible list somewhere, or can someone recommend one? I don't care if I have to upgrade to 10.10 or 11.04 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [check this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported).